# Can't sign in with Firebase Facebook sign In

Tags: ionic-framework, firebase, facebook-login, ionic2, firebase-authentication

I'm using Ionic2 and I'm trying to make Firebase Facebook Sign In work.

When I click on Facebook Sign In button inside my App I get this error:
[image]

These are my Facebook App settings:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Can you post the Ionic code where you're making the call to Facebook. The config part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are Using wrong oAuth redirect URIs, It should be like this

```
https://auth.firebase.com/v2/your-app-name-in-firebase/auth/facebook/callback
```